# GWT UIbinder auto complete is very slow

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I am working on GWT2.3 with Eclipse Ganymede version 3.4. 
While working with `UIBinder`, the auto complete feature (suggestions) is very slow.

I am not getting what to do in this situation. I need to add some plugins or files.
It too slow to work.

Comment: I have the same problem.  I'm using SpringSource Tool Suite 2.6.  It's blazing fast for everything else and I can go a whole month without even restarting it.  However, as soon as I type "g:" in a uibinder file it basically freezes for about 6 seconds.  I haven't searched for a solution yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment out the DOCTYPE as a work around.  It resolved the issue for me.

There's a discussion about this issue here:

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6262

And the solution posted by cave (comment #27) seems to be the easiest solution.